# Quick way to navigate to tiles on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I liked using tiles on windows 8.1 and had my frequently used apps at start, I could quickly press windows key and couple arrow keys to launch them. But on windows 10 if I press windows key and try to navigate tiles, it only works by pressing tab 3 times. Is there shortcut or something I can change to make sure tiles are selected by default when I press windows key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore the Windows 8.1 Start menu by doing the following:

Right-click the taskbar on an empty space and select Taskbar options.

On the left menu, click Start.

The 6th option should be: "Open start in Full Screen. Enable this option.

If you now press start, you can use the arrow keys directly to select any tile.